# numpy.ndarray.data attribute buffer object

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I create different `numpy` arrays as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])    # 2d array of integers
b = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,5.0]])  # 2d array of floats
c = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])  # 1d array of integers
d = np.array([10,20,30])           # different 1d array of integers


# python buffer object pointing to the start of the arrays data.
print(a.data)
print(b.data)
print(c.data)
print(d.data)
```

According to the numpy docs i expect to get a "*python buffer object pointing to the start of the arrays data*". Here is the official doc (from the numpy website): https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.data.html

So i would **expect a different memory address** for each array.

but i get this:

```
<memory at 0x000001EAE8B7CAD0>
<memory at 0x000001EAE8B7CAD0>
<memory at 0x000001EAE98E8A00>
<memory at 0x000001EAE98E8A00>
```

- The first two have the same memory buffer object pointer.
- And the second two have the same memory buffer object pointer.

Is `numpy` inferring the memory buffer object pointer based on the dimension of the array or if not, what is the rule that generates similar pointer addresses ?

Comment: That print display of the buffer object is not a memory address.  `a.__array_interface__['data']` is a more useful display.  But you can't use that in other code (such as the `buffer` parameter of `np.ndarray`).

Comment: If you print `a.data` several times in a row, you may get different print strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ipython session:

```
In [38]: type(a.data)
Out[38]: memoryview
```

and the `docs` for that object:

```
In [39]: a.data?
Type:        memoryview
String form: <memory at 0x000002AE38BAF5F0>
Length:      2
Docstring:   Create a new memoryview object which references the given object.
```

The print string of a memory view doesn't tell us anything about the databuffer address.

It can be used to make a `view` of the the array:

```
In [45]: aa = np.ndarray(a.shape, a.dtype, buffer=a.data)    
In [46]: aa
Out[46]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])    
In [47]: aa.base is a
Out[47]: True
```

The `data` of `__array_interface__` is closer to being a numeric address of the underlying data buffer.  I don't think it can be used in code, but I find it useful when checking whether an array is a view or copy:

```
In [48]: a.__array_interface__
Out[48]: 
{'data': (2947257325392, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'shape': (2, 3),
 'version': 3}
In [49]: aa.__array_interface__['data']
Out[49]: (2947257325392, False)
```

Comment: This is the clearest explanation as to the reason for the difference (and how to obtain the correct memory address too), so I have accepted this answer.

Comment: i do notice that `a.__array_interface__` returns a tuple like this: `(1765611310192, False)`. what does the `False` stand for ?

Answer (score 2):

They aren't sharing the same memory. `.data` creates a memoryview object every time the attribute is accessed.

You can see from this session that it's a different address every time:

```
>>> d.data
<memory at 0x6ffff70bddc0>
>>> d.data
<memory at 0x6ffff70bdb80>
>>> d.data
<memory at 0x6ffff70bd1c0>
```

In your case, the object is reclaimed immediately after `print()` and the next one created happens to have the same address.

Comment: i dont get this ?   if i run the code multiple times i still get the same addresses. i am using vscode (notebook, interactive and also the terminal) and it each case i get the same....

Comment: @D.L: Sorry, I had stepped away, but it seems the other answer has explained it.